# relationships of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I came across the following relationships, but I have no idea how to prove them. I would love to know they can be proved.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are both symmetric matrices,

relationship:
$$(X + Y)^{-1} = X^{-1} - X^{-1}(X^{-1} + Y^{-1})^{-1} X^{-1}$$
$$(X + Y)^{-1} = Y^{-1} - Y^{-1} (X^{-1} + Y^{-1})^{-1}Y^{-1}$$
$$(X + Y)^{-1} = X^{-1}(X^{-1}+Y^{-1})^{-1}Y^{-1}$$

I would like to know these relationships can be proved. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use following identity to prove the claims:
$$
A^{-1}B^{-1}=(BA)^{-1}.
$$
Start with the last one:
$$
X^{-1}(X^{-1}+Y^{-1})^{-1}Y^{-1}=((X^{-1}+Y^{-1})X)^{-1}Y^{-1}\\
=(I+Y^{-1}X)^{-1}Y^{-1}\\
=(Y(I+Y^{-1}X))^{-1}\\
=(Y+X)^{-1}.
$$
We use this to prove the first identity:
$$
(X + Y)^{-1} +X^{-1}(X^{-1} + Y^{-1})^{-1} X^{-1}= (X + Y)^{-1} +(X+Y)^{-1} Y X^{-1}\\
= (X + Y)^{-1}(I+Y X^{-1})\\
= (X + Y)^{-1}(X+Y) X^{-1}= X^{-1}\\
$$
The second identity follows by the same argument.

**Remark:** I did not see how symmetry assumption can be used. The only thing that is needed is $A,B$ being of same dimension and having inverses.