# Inverse of a sum of 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

One derivation I was verifying holds true if:

$$Q^{-1}\left(Q^{-1}+P^{-1}\right)^{-1}P^{-1}=\left(Q+P\right)^{-1}$$

where Q and P are positive definite matrices.

I've done some numerical tests and I incline to believe that.

But, where does this come from? I could not derive it from [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).

Comment: As a matter of fact it is true, @MartinR

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/769485/42969.